# Update MySql table from complicated Select

Tags: mysql

**I have complex SELECT request:**

```
select meta_value
from wp_posts v
left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
where meta_key in ('_price','_regular_price')
and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
and p.id = '1743'
limit 0,100
```

It returns me 4 (four) needed fields with values like

```
400
500
300
350
```

I need to update these values and set their values equal, for example `1000`.

Can I, based on my `SELECT`, run an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Yes. `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 100 WHERE id = (SELECT ....)` First create the select, and check is the desired id-s what you get. First create a backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any condition used in a `Select` query could be used in `Update` query, of course it might need a little modification. What you can do in your case is the following:
meta_value

```
Update wp_posts 
set meta_value = 1000
where id IN (select v.id
            from wp_posts v
            left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
            left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
            where v.meta_key in ('_price','_regular_price')
                and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
                and p.id = '1743')
```

Please note that I didn't test this, so I am not totally sure it will work. Make sure to backup your database before any queries like this. Hopefully it will give you the desired results.

**Edit**: I have assumed that `id` in `wp_posts` is a unique value.

Comment: OK i will test it today.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts WHERE meta_key in ( '_price' , '_regular_price' ) and v.post_' at line 2

Comment: Your select returns right id's : 1744 1744 1745 1745! But why It makes Error with Update?
SO id is unique. I tried to make UPDATE ...  meta_key =
 '_price' ...But ERROR again.

Comment: Could you show me the whole query you wrote please? I think you need to do it like `v.meta_key ... ` Of course if meta_key belongs to wp_posts

Comment: What if you need to set it to something a bit more complicated, such as the value in other parts of the joins?

Comment: @Michael Well, in that case, you will need to join the initial query to the other tables as well as the sub query.